# Looping Questions For A Game

Tags: python

I am starting to code a game just to practice. However, the user needs to enter an odd number to play. If they don't then I want the program to ask them for an odd number they loop and play again. I put this code in the else statement but if I enter an odd number it will not loop again.

Question 2:
how can I get the program to display Game 1, Game 2, etc as the loop runs however many times the input in 'Games' is?

Can someone help?

```
games = input("How many games would you like to play?")

for i in range(games):
  if games % 2 == 1:
     print('Game 1')
     # code here
  else:
     input('Enter an odd number')
```

Comment: A  `for` loop is the wrong tool here. You need to use a `while` loop with the appropriate conditional.

Comment: The downvote isn't mine, but I have problems understanding your question, too... Do you like to repeat asking for an odd number `games`-times? It seems to me that a `while` loop would be much better here. Then you could break it once the user inputs an odd number.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Comment: You asked two different questions, which makes your question too broad for SO standards. For the first one, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
games = int(input("How many games would you like to play?"))

while True:        
    if games % 2 == 1:        
        for i in range(games):          
            print('Game', i+1 )
        break

    else:
        games = int(input('Enter an odd number: '))
```

Comment: exactly what i was looking for. I need to practice while loops better. That was what i was missing. I did not know you can make the whole condition True then write a for loop under it.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me that you your confusion lies in a couple casting errors. Please note that `input` returns a type `string`, which you attempt to use as an `integer`. Try the following code instead:

```
games = input("How many games would you like to play? ")
numberOfGames = int(games)

for i in range(numberOfGames):
  print('Processing Game ' + str(i))
  testVal = input('Enter an odd number ')
  if int(testVal) % 2 == 1:
      print("Congratts! " + testVal + " is odd!\n\n")
  else:
      print("You Loose. " + testVal + " is even.\n\n")
```